# Set objects from rigth to left in titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I'm developing android application using Titanium 3.X. I need to add an image and a label (name) in a way that label is next to the image in same row and both should be right aligned. The problem is label text which represent a name is dynamic. So I can't set right property for the image view. I need to do this in a way which compatible with different devices (Screen sizes). I have given my font size as 11dp.
right property for image can be calculated by some algorithm which accepts font size, device screen width etc. But I couldn't identify it. Can anyone suggest me a way to resolve this ?

Comment: I could resolve this with the help of rect property of label.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I would add a view to wrap the image and label.  I would set the view's layout to horizontal.  I would then right align the view.

Comment: Please post the code in your original question.  Maybe myself or someone else can help with it.

Answer (score -1):

You should use a layout that will do the computations for you.
The RelativeLayout is quite useful in such situations. When you construction it in XML there are attributes like alignParentRight or layout_toRightOf that should prove useful. Don't forget to set the width of the TextView as wrap_content.

Comment: He is using Titanium, not straight android.